# no such table [appname]_userprofile

Tags: django

I'm writing my second Django app.  I currently have one table, and am confused by the errors I'm seeing. Let's say my app is named "genericapplication."

I have a table called UserProfile, which extends the Django user default table.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

So far so good.

But for some reason, Django seems to be adding an extra namespace to the table. I'm getting the following error:

"no such table: genericapplication_userprofile"

When I try to edit the table in my admin, I get the following error message:

OperationalError at /admin/genericapplication/userprofile/
no such table: genericapplication_userprofile

Here's my file structure:

```
/genericapplication
   manage.py
   db.sqlite3
   /genericapplication
     /static
     /templates
     __init.__py
     forms.py
     models.py
     settings.py
     urls.py
     views.py
     wsgi.py
```

Why is it renaming the table? I'm not sure what to look for here. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Django uses `<appname>_<tablename>` for the names of the database tables. You can override the table name with the `db_table` settings. For more info, [see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#table-names).

If you are getting a 'no such table' error, then it sounds like you need to create a migration for you app, and then run it.

Comment: As the guy said, by default django names tables appname_modelname. You probably need to run `python manage.py migrate` to create all the tables and/or check your database configuration.

Comment: The db_table settings fixed half of the problem (super helpful!).  My admin is still looking for userprofile inside of another folder though.

Comment: What do you mean by another folder? And why is your table not named the way django names them, did you create your database structure by hand?

Comment: I have migrated, and it doesn't register any changes when I do it again.  Mad Wombat, I don't understand the django name question, but the error I mention above -- OperationalError at /admin/genericapplication/userprofile/ -- makes it look like there is a file structure issue, no?

Comment: There is no file structure issue -  `/admin/genericapplication/userprofile/` is the correct url to edit user profiles in your `genericapplication` app.

Comment: If the table doesn't exist, then it's almost certainly a migrations problem. Create the migrations with `python manage.py makemigrations` then run them with `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: I've done both of those, and it's not detecting any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is, but running manage.py makemigrations  did the trick. makemigrations on its own did not detect changes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
python ./manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

It worked for me